# asking for a name of each customer with array size in for loop

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, arraylist

I'm a beginner and I've been really stuck on this problem. I'm not really sure how I can display the number of customer(in an arraySize) (customer #1, customer #2...) and ask for their name in a for loop.

```
String [] dinerArray;
//initialize our array
dinerArray = new String[arraySize];
for (int i = 1; i == arraySize; i++)
{
  System.out.println("enter the name of customer#" + arraySize + ": "
}
```

I've tried dinerArray.length and then i, arraySize with i, (i=0;i<=arraySize;i++) with arraySize/i.. but nothing seems to work. It would either only print once with customer#0 or print nothing at all

Comment: you need to check your `for`-Loop `for (int i=0; i<arraySize; ++i)`

Comment: @milbrandt I've tried putting i = 1 because I wanted the print line to say customer #1 and so forth, but it would only print once even when I enter 5 customers or 3 customers.. I've also tried putting dinerArray.length (i don't think that one is right..)

Answer (score 0):

im no Java dev but this is pretty basic.
The problem is that your for loop is just running if i is equal to arraySize, but this never happen.
So, try to change your '==' to a '<='

My solution:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int arraySize = 5;
String[] dinerArray = new String[arraySize];
for(int i = 1; i <= dinerArray.length; i++) {
    ystem.out.print("pleas enter name for customer#" + i);
    dinerArray[i - 1] = scan.nextLine();
}
```

Im not sure about the scanner think.

Comment: I've tried for (int i = 0; i <= dinerArray.length; i++)
      {
        System.out.println("enter the name of customer #" + i + ": ");
      } but it would only print customer #0 and then nothing more even when I enter 3 customers...

Comment: I don't understand the problem. So, it prints out 'bla bla customer#0', then u enter the name. What happens next?
Prints out nothing or 'bla bla customer#0' again?

Comment: Maybe something is going wrong with the scanner. Try without it. Just give it a dummy name and then print out the array, to be sure the loop isn't the problem

Comment: Please use `dinerArray[i-1]` - you will get an IndexOutOfBoundsException for the last Iteration: `dinerArray[dinerArray.length]`

Comment: uups, forgot it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to change arraySize to i. That way it will produce customer#1,customer#2 etc....

String [] dinerArray;
    //initialize our array
    dinerArray = new String[arraySize];
    for (int i = 1; i == arraySize; i++)
    {
      System.out.println("enter the name of customer#" + i+ ": ");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to read them from the console, you can use a Scanner:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

int arraySize = 10;
String[] dinerArray = new String[arraySize];

for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i)
{
    System.out.print("Enter the name of customer#" + (i + 1) + ": ");
    dinerArray[i] = input.nextLine();
}

input.close();
```